# Error: File cannot write on disk | WP, FTP, HOSTING

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, hosting, cpanel, glitch-framework

My website size is 12GB approved. On the Cpanel Web Disk it shows that  "Other Usage" is 34GB.

I have absolutely no idea what this additional 34GB is. Due to this, my hosting is not accepting to upload any files as the limit is only 40 GB. Currently total usage is approx 47GB.

[image]

Kindly help with "other usage" as unable to upload any file via either FTP or WordPress or directly from Hosting as well.

Comment: This is a question for Wordpress support, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It could be any of many files including logs, backups, scripts, email boxes (inbox, sent, trash etc).  Check your email boxes and make sure to clean them out by deleting old sent, spam etc.  Also if you can check your logs you might be able to clean them out as well.

Comment: So how do I do that from my File Hosting?

Comment: Do you have a control panel like Cpanel? Or perhaps you may have to ask your service provider.

Comment: Yes, we have cpanel interface & hosted on bigrock.in...Should be connected on Anydesk..?

Comment: I don't know what anydesk is. I would look into your cpanel and perhaps look for auto backups, full email boxes, log files etc.  Otherwise check with your provider and tell them you're trying to find out where all your storage space is being eaten up.

Comment: Well Anydesk is an alternate for teamviewer and yes I was suggesting if you can come to anyscreen sharing software so that i can share my screen with you?